# Mongo db update statement

Tags: mongodb, insert-update

I have simple document:

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "9cbfceec-d6f6-5638-b7c9-49103dc39665",
    "Settings" : [ 
        [ 
            "Storage", 
            "Dedicated"
        ], 
        [ 
            "Country", 
            "EE"
        ], 
        [ 
            "Address", 
            "http://localhost:55557"
        ], 
        [ 
            "Number", 
            "05"
        ]
    ]
}
```

can't figure out how to write update statement to update address information `"http://localhost:55557"` to IP address.something like `http://10.10.20.2:66667`

Comment: Such schema is extremely difficult to query and update in MongoDB. Consider modifying the schema such that the embedded arrays are flattened into a document with proper field/value pairs.

Comment: chridam- I cant update schema, if i could I fixed it with proper field/value pairs. I know it is not good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema design is incorrect, as there is no key for the value that you want to update. Consider changing your schema as follows

```
{
_id : "9cbfceec-d6f6-5638-b7c9-49103dc39665",
settings : 
    {  
        storage:"Dedicated", 
        country:"EE",
        address:"http://localhost:55557",
        number:"05"
    }
}
```

The above schema has key for every value in settings rather than having a double array. Any value is accessible and editable in the above document.

You can then update the document as follows

```
db.settings.update({
  _id: "9cbfceec-d6f6-5638-b7c9-49103dc39665"
}, {
  $set: {
    "settings.address": "http://10.10.20.2:66667"
  }
});
```

Comment: Your proposed solution should work if schema were good. but it doesn't solve my problem with double array. I cant modify schema.

Comment: there's no way to access the Address directly, as Address is not a key. Address is the first element in an array and the value associated with it is the second value. So the only way around it would be to find the document, retrieve the settings array and find the address by doing a string compare while iterating over the array. You will then update the value in the document then update the whole document in the collection.

Comment: Yes I already used that model you proposed.so i thought its possible to do more easily.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`chirdam` is right about schema .

If you don't have provision to make new schema you can try following :

Try this query :

```
db.yourCollection.update({"_id" : "9cbfceec-d6f6-5638-b7c9-49103dc39665", "Settings.Address" : "http://localhost:55557"} , { $set : {"Settings.$.Address" : "http://10.10.20.2:66667"}});
```

Or alternative is use `RoboMongo` to manually edit your collection

Comment: I know about the schema. Your solution also doesn't help in my case because it's double array.